# removing lines and characters while reading into an array

Tags: arrays, shell

Trying to write a shell script that will read in a text file which looks something like:

---

Line A `needs to be removed`

Line B `also to be removed`

Line C which has lots of things, including characters that need removing `should be the first to be read into an array position [0]`

Line D

.
.

Line "n"

---

What I need to do is read from `line C` up to line `n-1` into an array, but also remove the first 4 characters and the last 2 characters of the useful lines (Line C to Line n-1).

I can't seem to do anything other than read in the entire list, or print/echo the partial list but can't get that into an array.

I'm happy to multi-step it, rather than do it all in one line, but what ever is clean.

Comment: Shell is not programming language, and is intended for simple automation. Please consider switching to _real_ programming language like python, perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if works

```
head -n-1 txt | awk '{if($0~/LineC/){i=1}; if(i>0){print substr($0,5,length($0)-2)}}' txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It hasn't worked - just kept all lines. I'l just do a longer workaround, which is to edit the text file with python and then read in lines from the new file to perform the final function, which is shell specific.